# How do you get aws appsync to pick up relations when adding Aurora as graphql datasource

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, amazon-aurora

Using add-graphql-datasource, appsync is supposed to generate a graphql endpoint based on the existing structure of an aurora mysql serverless database. The database already has data in it.

Relational Databases Section at 
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql

However, the generated endpoint just has flat representations of the data - none of the relations that exist in database.

How can you use add-graphql-datasource to generate the relations as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of writing, the `add-graphql-datasource` command does not support auto-generating logic for relations. You can use the `add-graphql-datasource` command to get started and then write your own resolver logic to implement the relations.